# MSSQL , PHP Connection issues, accessing a database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, drupal

I am trying to connect to a database for a client (I'm a student), the website is using drupal and connects to their live stock with a module called SPNET, the MSSQL connection details are as follows:

```
localhost,1433
database: techtech
username: tech1
password: EXAMPLEPASSWORD
```

that works fine, but now im trying to connect to the same database with PHP, as follows:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost:1433";
$userDB = "tech1";
$passwordDB = "EXAMPLEPASSWORD";

$database = "techtech";
$link = mssql_connect($host, $userDB, $passwordDB);

if (!$link) {
die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

I am given this error:

```
Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: localhost:1433
```

I am not sure how to fix this problem, this .php file is located on the same server as drupal is connecting.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 1433 is the standard port for MSSQL, you don't have to specify it when connecting with `mssql_connect()`. If you want to specify a different port, you need to use this format:

```
 $host = "localhost,1433";
```